# Moodle Web Services via SOAP from PHP

Tags: php, soap, moodle

I'm trying to connect to our moodle server via SOAP web service from PHP.
I'm trying to run the mod_assign_get_assignments function, but I'm receiving a 'invalidparameter' message.
I can get the function to return the expected data via REST, but need to get it working via SOAP.

Here is the code I'm using...

```
<?php

$serverurl = "http://moodlehost/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=763b54a6exxxx989be353xxxx6cca5f6";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($serverurl);

 try
    {
        $soapClient->__soapCall('mod_assign_get_assignments', array("courseids" => array(10889), "includenotenrolledcourses" => 1));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo("<pre>");
        print_r($e);
        echo("</pre>");
    }

?>
```

Can someone please try this against their own moodle server and see if you get an error as I am??

..or I'd love it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

..is it just me, or is the moodle web services documentation hard to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that you have SOAP turned on in your Web Service protocols admin. You can access this page at admin/settings.php?section=webserviceprotocols

Try clicking the eye with the strike through it to enable it (if it isn't already).

[image: manage protocols]